# Using Combo Box text for part of a Binding Source

Tags: vb.net

Hello I am trying to display data in a grid view using a combo box containing multiple databases. Each database has a binding source. However, instead of coding a huge select statement is there a way that I can use the TableList.SelectedText and put it in front of the BindingSource so I don't have to code so many instances?

I tried doing it below but it does not work.

```
Private Sub TableList_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TableList.SelectedIndexChanged
        DataGridView1.DataSource = TableList.SelectedText(BindingSource)
        DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = True
```

Comment: `SelectedText` is not what you probably think it is.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: I want to use either .SelectedText or .Text for whatever is selected in the combo box so that it may be meshed with the binding source to create the correct path.